# SQL: How to determine the most frequent data length in the DB column?

Tags: sql, statistics, db2

Need to analyze values' length in DB column and get the % of the Number of the values with the same length.

Desire result:

```
            Same length values in COL1 = 70%  with LENGTH = 10 chars
```

It's not a 'find most frequent value and calculate its length', because if we have a KEY or ID column with high cardinality - all values will be different.

Need some fast-working SQL (DB2 dialect is prefered) - not to overload the DB engine (billions of rows).

**Example 1**

```
         COL1 (VARCHAR 10) 
         ------------------
                     X01   
                     X02   
                     X03   
                     X04   
                     X05
```

Result:

```
            100%, 3
```

**Example 2**

```
           COL1(VARCHAR 20)
         -------------------------
                    New York
                    London
                    Los Angeles
                    Paris
                    San Francisco
```

Result:

```
            20%, 5 
           (or 20%, 13 - does not matter because values are different)
```

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: How many columns do you have? Dynamic?

Comment: @GenWan for simplicity - let's do 1 column check, static

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single SELECT statement using `GROUP BY GROUPING SETS` operator for any number of columns. The example below presumes, that the constants are result of the corresponding length(varchar_col).

```
with tab as (
select
  length(a) a
, length(b) b
, count(1) cnt
, grouping(length(a)) a_grp
, grouping(length(b)) b_grp
from table(values
  ('X01', 'New York')     
, ('X02', 'London')       
, ('X03', 'Los Angeles')  
, ('X04', 'Paris')        
, ('X05', 'San Francisco')
) t (a, b)
group by grouping sets ((length(a)), (length(b)), ())
)
, row_count as (select cnt from tab where a_grp + b_grp = 2)
, top as (
select a, b, cnt, rownumber() over(partition by a_grp, b_grp order by cnt desc) rn_
from tab
where a_grp + b_grp  = 1 -- number of columns - 1
)
select a, b, cnt, 100*cnt/nullif((select cnt from row_count), 0) pst
from top
where rn_=1;

 A  B CNT PST
-- -- --- ---
 3  -   5 100
 -  5   1  20
```

Comment: thanks, but it calculates only the lenght of the most freq. value lenght. Not what I need

Comment: 1-st 2 columns are lengths of the rows with the most frequent length. 3-rd column is a number of records with the corresponding length. The last column is percentage of such rows with such a length. I've rewritten the query according your example with strings.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select concat(cast(rnk1 as float)/cast (totalcol1 as float)*100,'%'), col1length
from (
select *
, row_number () over (partition by col1length order by col1length) rnk1
from (
select length(col1) as col1length
,(select count(col1) from test) as totalcol1
from test)t1
order by rnk1 desc
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY)t2
```

Test Result:

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=477f3418814602513a8017516ef7945d)

Comment: Thanks! I will try

Comment: @gmlvsv 'Order by' also kills the performance. You can replace it with max().